# Setting std::io_base flags for custom stream class

Tags: c++, iostream, cout, flags, ostringstream

I have a custom class called Stream

```
class Stream
public:
    Stream& operator<<(int i) { stream_ << i; return *this;}
            template <typename CustomClass>
            Stream& operator<<(const CustomClass& c) { stream_ << c.toString() /* assume this template always have toString(); return *this; }
private:
    std::stringstream stream_;
};
```

This is a very basic example of what I actually have. And I am trying to set std::ios_base flags like following:

```
Stream() << 1 << std::hex << 2;
```

using operator;

```
Stream& operator<<(std::ios_base& b) { stream_.setf(b.flags()); return *this; }
```

from what I understand, because std::hex returns std::ios_base so it should call this and set streams' flag. But it always call the template. Note: If i remove this template, everything works just as good as you would expect but is there a way to have both?

Please feel free to ask further if you need more clarification

Comment: Just to clarify a bit more what I am trying is to make **ios_base** overloaded operator !important over template. I believe this is very weird behaviour since templates should be put at the very last if no other type could be resolved at compile time it should be used. and I believe std library is linked before all other libraries.

Comment: btw even if i return `std::ios_base&` and return stream, this does not do the job i mean it still calls template over typed overload

Answer (score 0):

IOStream manipulators are not objects of type `std::ios_base`, they are functions that take and return `std::ios_base` references. So when you want to do stream insertion regarding these objects, you have to overload for *function pointers*:

```
Stream& operator<<(std::ios_base& (*manip)(std::ios_base&))
//                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
{
    manip(this->stream);
    return *this;
}
```